# Could Flink different task share same variable in the same task manager?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a param `p` which is read only, like a machine learning model. And suppose I could use distributed cache to cache the file on each task manager thus each task could load it locally.

if `map(new MyMapFunction(p))`, `p` would be serialized and deserialized to each operator, and if cached and load, each task would load an instance of `p`. Suppose I have 4 task manager, each 8 slots, we could `flink run -p 32` to use all the resources and `p` would have 32 instances.

Theoretically it could be done by `p` only have 4 instances I suppose, and each threads could use the instance in same task manager? Could it work in Flink?

Comment: I don't know whether it's a good practice or not, but I had a similar case - a common cache across 16 slots per TM and I used just a static variable (val in object in scala) and it worked well. Just need to make it thread-safe.

Comment: It's a good idea! But I am considering take `getRuntimeContext` in the object method because I want to get the file cached by `registeredCachedFile`, and the context is created after job submit. However thus this object should be created after submit and before `open` in `MyMapFunction`. Seems tricky?

Comment: you could probably try to check whether the object is already initialized or not within the `open()` method and guarded by some `Lock` in object - if not, then inside `open()` take `getRuntimeContext`, extract the cached file and initialize `object` with this file. After that, the object will be initialized and other TMs in `open()` will already see initialized object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the following approach to initialize the per-TM common structure:

```scala
class EventProcess extends ProcessFunction[Event, Event] {

  ...

  override def open(parameters: Configuration): Unit = {
    super.open(parameters)

    EventProcess.init()
  }

  ...
}

object EventProcess {

  val lock = "1"
  var data: Any = _

  def init(config: Config): Unit = {
    lock.synchronized {
      if (data == null) {
        // do init
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In your case, if you need to take smth from `RuntimeCOntext` inside `open()` and initialize your object `var` with this, you can use synchronization inside `open()`:

```scala
override def open(parameters: Configuration): Unit = {
    super.open(parameters)

    EventProcess.lock.synchronized {
      if (EventProcess.YOUR_VAR == null) {
        EventProcess.init(getRuntimeContext()...)
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: It is better to modify some large pieces of code to pseudocode

Comment: Solution looks okay, but I recommend to drop the volatiles as it's an expensive no-op as is.

Comment: @ArvidHeise I would say that `@volatile` is required as multiple threads will be accessing the same variable so it's potentially possible that one of the threads won't see the changes made to it.

Comment: If you acquire a lock, it also serves as memory barrier. So you apply a happen before relationship between the update and the read.

Comment: @ArvidHeise you are right, thank you! I haven't taken into account synchronized block. Updated the answer without the volatiles.

Answer (score 2):

It's completely viable to use static variables to share heavy read-only data structures across different instances. Make sure you use some kind of lock to avoid reinitializing and guarantee visibility.

```
class MyMap extends RichMapFunction {
    private static Model model;

    public void open() {
        if (model == null) {
            synchronized (MyMap.class) {                
                if (model == null) {
                    model = // read model ...
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How about in scala?

Comment: In scala I used simply val inside object:

object EventProcess {
 var alreadyTrackedBucketIdsCache: Cache[String, String] = _

 ...
}

Comment: @MikalaiLushchytski I need to do load operation in `open()` because I need the `RuntimeContext`, could it done by val inside object?

Comment: Yes, I also did it in open - just added additional `@volatile` var initialized = false which set to true on first initialization

Comment: I just introduced `init()` method in my `object`, where I initialized the target `val`. The initialization was synchronized by this and `@volatile var initialized` was to `true` on first call. This way all TMs tried to init() my static variabe on `open()`, but only the first one did the actual initialization.

Comment: @MikalaiLushchytski could you provide the example code as answer? I did not get that how could a val of object be initialized in `init()`